# Google Sheets bacthUpdate range fetches wrong array indexes

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, google-sheets-api, indexof

I have the following data in a google sheet and I attempting to fetch the update each row (N) where array value 5 matches yesterdays date. (Please note I had to csv the data in order to paste it here properly but it is in an excel sheet with the top row frozen)

**Data before running**

```
idRef|fName  |lName|tourType|dateBooked|tourDate  |Pax|phone    |pickupAddress|Op|emailAddress     |bookedSent|reminderSent|feedbackSent
1    |Josh   |w    |group   |2019-02-12|2019-11-09|3  |821467371|test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
12   |Jess   |s    |group   |2019-02-22|2019-11-10|2  |1233333  |test address |as|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
2    |Nick   |J    |group   |2019-02-11|2019-11-11|2  |821234124|test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
3    |Mars   |M    |group   |2019-02-08|2019-11-09|2  |821234124|test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
4    |Nicole |M    |group   |2019-02-07|2019-11-10|5  |54546456 |test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
5    |Tim    |M    |group   |2019-02-08|2019-11-11|2  |821234124|test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
6    |Sue    |h    |group   |2019-02-09|2019-11-09|3  |34534534 |test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
7    |carl   |M    |group   |2019-02-10|2019-11-10|8  |54546456 |test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
8    |peter  |M    |private |2019-02-11|2019-11-11|2  |54546456 |test address |GC|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
9    |jim    |M    |private |2019-02-12|2019-11-09|6  |54546456 |test address |GC|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
10   |bianca |M    |private |2019-02-13|2019-11-10|3  |54546456 |test address |GC|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
11   |richman|M    |private |2019-02-14|2019-11-11|2  |54546456 |test address |GC|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0
```

**Code**

```
            const fs = require('fs');
            const readline = require('readline');
            const { google } = require('googleapis');

            const SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";

            const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

            fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
                if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
                authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
            });

            /**
             * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
             * given callback function.
             * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
             * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
             */
            function authorize(credentials, callback) {
                const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
                const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
                    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

                fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
                    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
                    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
                    callback(oAuth2Client);
                });
            }

            /**
             * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
             * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
             * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
             * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
             */
            function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
                const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
                    access_type: 'offline',
                    scope: SCOPES,
                });
                console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
                const rl = readline.createInterface({
                    input: process.stdin,
                    output: process.stdout,
                });
                rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
                    rl.close();
                    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
                        if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
                        // Store the token to disk for later program executions
                        fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                            if (err) return console.error(err);
                            console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
                        });
                        callback(oAuth2Client);
                    });
                });
            }

            /**
             * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
             * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxx/edit
             * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
             */
            function listMajors(auth) {

                var today = new Date();
                today = today.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

                var dateYesterday = new Date();
                dateYesterday.setDate(dateYesterday.getDate() - 1);
                dateYesterday = dateYesterday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

                var dayYesterday = new Date();
                var days = [
                    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
                ];
                dayYesterday.setDate(dayYesterday.getDate() - 1);
                dayYesterday = days[dayYesterday.getDay()];

                var dateTomorrow = new Date();
                dateTomorrow.setDate(dateTomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                dateTomorrow = dateTomorrow.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

                var dayTomorrow = new Date();
                var futureDays = [
                    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
                ];
                dayTomorrow.setDate(dayTomorrow.getDate() + 1);
                dayTomorrow = futureDays[dayTomorrow.getDay()];

                const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
                sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
                    spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                    range: 'A2:N',
                }, (err, res) => {
                    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                    const rows = res.data.values;

                    var data = res.data.values;
                    var filteredRows = data.filter(eachRow);
                    function eachRow(eachRow) {
                        return (eachRow[13] === '0' || 'undefined') && eachRow[5] === dateYesterday; //2019-02-17
                    }

                    if (filteredRows != 0) {
                        for (x = 0; x < filteredRows.length; x++) {
                            console.log(filteredRows[x].join());
                            console.log(filteredRows[x][0]);

                            // let selectedRowIndex =  filteredRows[x][0]+1 ;

                            let selectedRowIndex = rows.indexOf(filteredRows[x]);
                            console.log("Index: " + selectedRowIndex);

                            ////////////////////UPDATING START////////////////////////////
                            fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
                                if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
                                // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
                                authorize(JSON.parse(content), updateCells);
                            });
                            /**
             * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
             * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxx/edit
             * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.
             */
                            function updateCells(auth) {

                                var sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4' });

                                authorize(function () {
                                    var request = {
                                        spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxx',  // 
                                        valueInputOption: 'RAW',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

                                        resource: {

                                            "data": [
                                                {
                                                    "range": "N" + selectedRowIndex,
                                                    "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",

                                                    "values": [
                                                        [
                                                            1
                                                        ],

                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },

                                        auth,
                                    };
                                    console.log(selectedRowIndex);
                                    sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate(request, function (err, response) {
                                        if (err) {
                                            console.error(err);
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
                                    });
                                });

                                function authorize(callback) {

                                    var auth = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";

                                    if (auth == null) {
                                        console.log('authentication failed');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    callback(auth);
                                }
                            }
                            ////////////////////UPDATING END////////////////////////////
                        }
                    };

                });
            }
```

**Data after running**

```
idRef|fName  |lName|tourType|dateBooked|tourDate  |Pax|phone    |pickupAddress|Op|emailAddress     |bookedSent|reminderSent|feedbackSent
1    |Josh   |w    |group   |2019-02-12|2019-11-09|3  |821467371|test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
12   |Jess   |s    |group   |2019-02-22|2019-11-10|2  |1233333  |test address |as|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |1           
2    |Nick   |J    |group   |2019-02-11|2019-11-11|2  |821234124|test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
3    |Mars   |M    |group   |2019-02-08|2019-11-09|2  |821234124|test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
4    |Nicole |M    |group   |2019-02-07|2019-11-10|5  |54546456 |test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |1           
5    |Tim    |M    |group   |2019-02-08|2019-11-11|2  |821234124|test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
6    |Sue    |h    |group   |2019-02-09|2019-11-09|3  |34534534 |test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
7    |carl   |M    |group   |2019-02-10|2019-11-10|8  |54546456 |test address |AS|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |1           
8    |peter  |M    |private |2019-02-11|2019-11-11|2  |54546456 |test address |GC|test@mydomain.com|sent      |0           |0           
9    |jim    |M    |private |2019-02-12|2019-11-09|6  |54546456 |test address |GC|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
10   |bianca |M    |private |2019-02-13|2019-11-10|3  |54546456 |test address |GC|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0           
11   |richman|M    |private |2019-02-14|2019-11-11|2  |54546456 |test address |GC|test@mydomain.com|notSent   |0           |0
```

As you can see, the code updates the cells in col N but not at the correct index. IE the above should update each col N where col F = 2019-11-09 (to yesterdays relative date) to value 1 but it is skipping the correct row by 1 each time.

In the updateCells batchUpdate function I am calling  `"range": "N" + selectedRowIndex,`
I am able to update multiple cells upon running however the selectedRowIndex isnt matching up with the correct rows actual location (all rows where val 5 = yesterdays date). I scratched around a bit with the variable being inaccessible from outside the scope of the for loop located a little higher up by using a function call but no luck either. The problem I think seems to be that the first row is a frozen row. In my function higher up, **listMajors** `range: 'A2:N',` calls the correct data without the header cell but how can I apply this starting point to my second batchUpdate function. Or do I need to map a new array or something? Is there not a way to specific the range like with the sheets.value.get function?

Please, why doesn't `selectedRowIndex` select and update the correct rows?

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet before and after the correct script was run? By this, I would like to think of the issue. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Tanaike, (pls forgive the csv text from the spreadsheet, I am unable to paste a formatted table with the data) two things to clarify, please bear in mind that the code is dependent on the date field in column 5  being yesterdays date and the idRef in col 0 is not the same as the array index which I am trying to use correctly use. Then to answer you question, when I run the above code on the above data (where col 5 is yesterdays date) it updates the incorrect row my 1. I have edited the question to add more info and example data before and after running. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. From your updated question and replying, I could confirm that the last columns of the values `12,Jess,s,group,2019-02-22,2019-11-10,2,1233333,test address,as,test@mydomain.com,notSent,0,1`, `4,Nicole,M,group,2019-02-07,2019-11-10,5,54546456,test address,AS,test@mydomain.com,sent,0,1`, `7,carl,M,group,2019-02-10,2019-11-10,8,54546456,test address,AS,test@mydomain.com,sent,0,1` was modified from `0` to `1`.

Comment: In this case, when the today is `2019-11-11`, when the value of the column "F" is `2019-11-10` which is yesterday, the last column is modified to `1`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct yes, Tanaike. The last column being feedbackSent should be updated to 1.

Comment: And regarding your previous reply, indeed some updating takes place but at the incorrect index. Also the above data should have given you 4 results not 3. I see you appeared to have updated the correct columns but it still doesn't behave as expected on my end, there might be a problem reproducing the issue on your side, sorry its a bit messy but if I run it on the same data it updates the column but 1 index to far IE for Jess the expected edit would be N3 = 1 but on my side it updates N4 and seems to skip the last iteration/loop.

Comment: The date value should be the date object formatted as (yyyy"-"mm"-"dd) - I click the 123 menu (more date and time formats) in Google Sheets to check this.

Comment: In the console it appears that the loop is failing on the first try when trying to update cell N0, there seems to be an issue with reading the original arrays starting index or with the frozen header row causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it. If you want to be simpler your script, for example, how about using `spreadsheets.values.get` and `spreadsheets.values.update`?

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, I actually am using `spreadsheets.values.get` and `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` in my script and indeed yes I seemed to have answered my own question. My problem was related to adjusting the start index after `.filter` to skip 2 initial rows as shown below.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information.

Answer (score 0):

While I have somewhat of a solution it doesn't seem very elegant, I used the following to get it working but I am not quite sure *why* it works.

(The below code is inside the for loop, `for (x = 0; x < filteredRows.length; x++)`)

`var startingIndex = 2;
let selectedRowIndex = rows.indexOf(filteredRows[x]) + startingIndex;

console.log("Index of original array: " + selectedRowIndex) ;`

Provides expected behavior but I am still unsure to the root of the cause.

UPDATE: I wasn't accounting for the top row as well as my frozen top row so therefore `var startingIndex = 2;` works as it should.